# select query records if multiple type is matched

Tags: php, mysql

I have some mysql tables like below,

**1)videos**

```
id      name
1       test1
2       test2
```

**2)tags**

```
id      name
1       theme1=test1
2       theme1=test2
3       theme2=test1
4       theme2=test2
5       age=senior
6       age=children
```

**3)tags_to_items**

```
vid    tagid
1      1
1      5
```

Here in table `tags_to_item` you see `videos.id=1` has 2 tags
`1)theme1=test1` AND `2)age=senior`. It means `video.id=1` has 2 tags.
Now here is one conflict,
what i am doing now is, i am searching for theme's only. It means if i search where theme1=theme1 then it need to also search theme1 in theme2 and vice versa. like this

```
WHERE tagid=1 OR tagid=2
```

This is functioning proper, but now i want to search if video have multiple tag with AND condition like this

```
WHERE tagid=5 AND tagid IN (1,2)
```

It should return `video.id=1`

So, probably it need to search where video 1 contains tag tag `age=senior` AND `theme1=theme1` OR  `theme2=theme1`. But its not working, anyone have idea how can i do like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i got the answer.
I need to do join like this,

```
INNER JOIN tags_to_items t2      ON (v.id = t2.tagid AND t2.tagid = 5) 

INNER JOIN tags_to_items t3      ON (v.id = t3.tagid AND t3.tagid in ('27' ,'69','84' ,'99' ))
```

Comment: Are you sure to join the viedeo ID equal to the tagid? Furthermore I don't think you need to do 2 inner joins. And your "tagid" is different from your example. Please have another look at the first code blocke of my answer

Comment: @bish data is just sample, i have big database with many tags and many filters, so joins are dynamic according to tag search. it will be 2 or 3 or many.